# PHP preg_replace() Unknown modifier '>'

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Ошибка - Unknown modifier '>'

```
preg_replace('/<br />/','',$news);
```

Ошибка - Unknown modifier 'h'

```
preg_replace('/</h1>/','',$title);
```

Поправьте пожалуйста, что я не так сделал

правильно ли исправил?

```
preg_replace('/<br \/>/','',$news); 

preg_replace('/<\/h1>/','',$title);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы забыли экранировать символы `/`. Правильно:

```
preg_replace('/<br \/>/','',$news);
```

и

```
preg_replace('/<\/h1>/','',$title);
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже догадался :)

Comment: @Dikkiy, если я правильно ответил на ваш вопрос, отметьте ответ как "правильный" =)